# HSQLDB with JdbcTemplate, nothing is getting saved

Tags: hsqldb

For some reason after doing changes to my file based HSQL database and shutting down the java process, nothing seems to be saved in the database. I.E. i can rerun this program over and over without meeting the "table already exists" exception. What the hell is going on?!

Main class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TestApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DbConfig.class, TestDao.class);
        JdbcTemplate template = ctx.getBean(JdbcTemplate.class);
        TestDao dao = ctx.getBean(TestDao.class);
        dao.testTransactionality();
    }
}
```

Config:

```
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class DbConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource(){
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:file:databaseFiles/test/");
        ds.setUsername("sa");
        ds.setPassword("1");
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(DataSource ds){
        return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource){
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }
}
```

DAO:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Transactional
public class TestDao {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate template;

    @Transactional
    public void testTransactionality(){
        template.execute("create table LIBRARY (LIBRARY_ID INT, LIBRARY_TITLE VARCHAR(400))");
        template.execute("insert into library values (1, 'Library')");
    }
}
```

I have tried doing something similar with plain JDBC classes as well as doing explicit commits, nothing seems to help. I am guessing it's a HSQLDB problem. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database URL is not quite right (shouldn't end with a slash). You should also change the write delay to 0 to see the changes:

```
ds.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:file:databaseFiles/test;hsqldb.write_delay_millis=0");
```